# Can't refresh pop up window using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I have a html page to handle a shopping cart view. I used jquery and ajax to show it in a pop up window.  I can display items in the pop up window. I have a delete button in the pop up window, which allows me to delete items from my shopping cart. I want to refresh the pop up window after I click on the delete button. But now, after I click on the delete button, the pop up window disappears and it redirects me to the normal html page. 
Here is my jquery. `loadmodal` is a plugin I downloaded from Internet.

```
$(function(){
$('#cart').off('click.login').on('click.login',function(){

    $('body').loadmodal({

        id:'cart',
        title:'Shopping Cart',
        url:'/myproject/cartDisplay/',

    }); 

});
});
```

My delete code (I am writing my project in django):

```
def process_request(request):

cart = request.session.get('cart',{})

id=request.urlparams[0]
del cart[id]
request.session["cart"]=cart    

return HttpResponseRedirect('/project/cartDisplay/')
```

Comment: polls/cartDisplay should be /myproject/cartDisplay/

Comment: Then edit your question instead of commenting :)